# ArgumentOutOfRangeException in ASP.Net ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently getting a very strange error in the ViewBag of my View file.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index

Line 6 is the cause of the error:

```
Line 4:      ViewBag.Title = "Home";
Line 5:      ViewBag.StyleSheet = "Main/Home";
Line 6:      ViewBag.Description = "This description will be used by the _ViewStart page.";
```

I've tried removing Line 6 but it will then throw the Error on Line 5.

I have absolutely no clue how such error can be caused by the ViewBag, Especially strings.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

**EDIT:** There isn't much to see in the View File. But here is more:

```
@using Company.Product.Extenstions; // Just noticed the misspelling there...

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    ViewBag.StyleSheet = "Main/Home";
    ViewBag.Description = "This description will be used by the _ViewStart page.";
}

<div class="hero">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div id="most-downloaded">
            <h2>Most Downloaded</h2>
```

And the Controller function:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.MostDownloaded = ItemService.GetItems(ItemType.Document, "downloads", "desc", 6);
    ViewBag.MostRecent = ItemService.GetItems(ItemType.Document, "time", "desc", 4);

    ViewBag.OnlineUsers = HttpContext.Application["OnlineUsers"];
    ViewBag.TotalUsers = UserService.GetUsersCount();
    ViewBag.TotalItems = ItemService.GetItemCount();

    return View();
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException() +72
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index) +34
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Int32 ) +185
   ASP._Page_Views_Main_Index_cshtml.Execute() in e:\Path\To\Project\Views\Main\Index.cshtml:6
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +97
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +295
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629296
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: That error is most definitely not caused by the ViewBag. You must be referencing a collection in your view and you are accessing an element outside its bounds.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the view file--at least enough for us to get a clearer idea of what's really going on here?

Comment: I've updated the post to contain more information about the view file, Also added the code from the Controller.

Comment: Could you post a StackTrace? Also, the problem is most likely in one of your collections (`MostDownloaded` or `MostRecent`). Line-numbers gets messed up from time to time for various reasons.

Comment: I've added the Stack Trace. I'm not sure what the problem really is because my friend got the code working on 2 of his machines, without this error.

Comment: I've tried running it with everything from the Controller code commented (Except `return View()` of course). And the error still persists.

Comment: So is your ItemService getting items asynchronously? It seems like concurrency race going on, or something like that...

Comment: Nothing is retrieved asynchronously so far I can tell. The ItemService calls the Repository and that directly communicates with the Database. And this shouldn't be the problem because it still errors even with those lines removed.